# Versel TurboRepo has got a conflict with expo router installation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo, react-native-web, expo-router

I'm using [TurboRepo](https://turbo.build/repo/docs) to build a monorepo and the [react-native-web](https://github.com/vercel/turbo/tree/main/examples/with-react-native-web) example for kicking off full example of expo react-native-web.

I want to install `expo-router` but I can't implement it properly within the `native` project. I read the docs of the `expo-router` significantly. If I add `index.js` file in the root of the `native` project and write `import 'expo-router/entry`  inside it, I would get this error:

```
Web Bundling failed 787ms
error: index.js: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
```

If I remove the `index.js` file and add the entry file inside the `package.json` file by using the `main` key, (Like the docs said) I would get this error:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ./node_modules/expo-router/entry from /Users/amerllica/WebstormProjects/mini-market-app/apps/_e_customer/.: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules/expo-router/entry(.web.ts|.ts|.web.tsx|.tsx|.web.js|.js|.web.jsx|.jsx|.web.json|.json|.web.cjs|.cjs)
  * node_modules/expo-router/entry/index(.web.ts|.ts|.web.tsx|.tsx|.web.js|.js|.web.jsx|.jsx|.web.json|.json|.web.cjs|.cjs)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/amerllica/WebstormProjects/mini-market-app/apps/_e_customer/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:114:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/amerllica/WebstormProjects/mini-market-app/apps/_e_customer/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:277:43)
    at /Users/amerllica/WebstormProjects/mini-market-app/apps/_e_customer/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:169:21
    at Server._resolveRelativePath (/Users/amerllica/WebstormProjects/mini-market-app/apps/_e_customer/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1045:12)
    at async Server.requestProcessor [as _processBundleRequest] (/Users/amerllica/WebstormProjects/mini-market-app/apps/_e_customer/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:449:37)
    at async Server._processRequest (/Users/amerllica/WebstormProjects/mini-market-app/apps/_e_customer/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:383:7)
```

**Weird:** The `native` project alongside `expo-router` works properly individually outside of the mono repo.

**Goal:** Clean install of `expo-router` to have run on Android, iOS and web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Assuming you have started your project with `npx create-turbo@latest -e with-react-native-web` from [Turborepo & React Native Starter](https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/turborepo-react-native)

We have to make sure that there's no problem on dependencies before we install and add `expo-router`

- Select `yarn workspace` (it could be whatever you want)
- Update expo version to `~49.0.7`. Then, re-install dependencies again from the project's root
- Run `sudo npx expo install --check`, then fix the dependencies
- At this point, the project can be successfuly run without any errors. We can now proceed and add `expo-router`

---

##### Used this [expo-router docs](https://docs.expo.dev/routing/installation/#quick-start) as a guide

- Run `npx expo install expo-router react-native-safe-area-context react-native-screens expo-linking expo-constants expo-status-bar react-native-gesture-handler`
- Re-install dependencies again from project's root
- Remove `index.js`'s content and replace it with `import "expo-router/entry";`. See [working with monorepos guide](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/monorepos/)
- Set `"scheme": "turborepo-with-expo-router"` in `app.json` (Replace the schema with whatever you like)
- Add `plugins: ["expo-router/babel"],` in `babel.config.js`
- Enable developing for web by adding the ff. in app.json

  ```js
  "web": {
    "bundler": "metro",
  },
  ```
- Create `.env` file and add `EXPO_USE_METRO_WORKSPACE_ROOT=1`
- Finally, remove `App.tsx` and start creating the first page in `/app`